# Select one specfic row from each user by a different time

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the last answer for a specific question. My current solution selects only the Question from "Nutzer1237", but i want the last Answer from "Nutzer1234" too.

[image]

```
SELECT pid, frage, antwort, user, created_at
FROM antwortenverlauf
WHERE frage =  'Risiko: Wie empfinden Sie die Kommunikation mit dem Kunden?'
AND (
user, created_at
)
IN (

SELECT user, MAX( created_at ) 
FROM antwortenverlauf
)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Sorry for my English!

Translation:
frage = question

antwort = answer

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have read the answer of @fancyPants

```
SELECT pid, frage, antwort, user, created_at
FROM antwortenverlauf a1
WHERE frage =  'Risiko: Wie empfinden Sie die Kommunikation mit dem Kunden?'
    AND (user, created_at) IN (SELECT user, MAX( created_at ) 
                               FROM antwortenverlauf a2
                               WHERE a1.frage=a2.frage 
                               GROUP BY USER)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

In the **[official manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html)** there are 3 examples how to solve this.

> *Task: For each article, find the dealer or dealers with the most*
>   expensive price.
>
> This problem can be solved with a subquery like this one:

```
SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM   shop s1
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
              FROM shop s2
              WHERE s1.article = s2.article);
```

> The preceding example uses a correlated subquery, which can be
>   inefficient (see Section 13.2.10.7, “Correlated Subqueries”). Other
>   possibilities for solving the problem are to use an uncorrelated
>   subquery in the FROM clause or a LEFT JOIN.
>
> Uncorrelated subquery:

```
SELECT s1.article, dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
JOIN (
  SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price
  FROM shop
  GROUP BY article) AS s2
  ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price = s2.price;
```

> LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
```

> The LEFT JOIN works on the basis that when s1.price is at its maximum
>   value, there is no s2.price with a greater value and the s2 rows
>   values will be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Your query works as expected giving the record with `Nutzer1237` as 'user', because, in your subquery, you're looking for the records with the most recent timestamp: `MAX( created_at )` without grouping your results per `user`.

You have then to group the results per `user` in your subquery, using this query:

```
SELECT user, MAX( created_at ) 
FROM antwortenverlauf
GROUP BY user
```

Note: Make sure also that the value of the `frage` column you're looking for doesn't contain undesired spaces or other characters.

However, your query won't get your desired results because you're looking for the `MAX(created_at)` without considering the `frage` column. You have to move the `WHERE` condition in your subquery. Your final query will then look like this:

```
SELECT pid, frage, antwort, user, created_at
FROM antwortenverlauf
WHERE (user, created_at)
IN (    
SELECT user, MAX( created_at ) 
FROM antwortenverlauf
WHERE frage =  'Risiko: Wie empfinden Sie die Kommunikation mit dem Kunden?'
GROUP BY user
)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: thats not correct. Please have a look at created_at one row before

Comment: www0.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=54039041 Have a look at the picture! with max(created_at) u only select the maximum created_at from a user. But the Question from Nutzer1234 'Risiko: Wie empfinden Sie die Kommunikation mit dem Kunden?' is not the maximum of created_at

Comment: @user2799097 Have you had a look at my updated answer? It is very similar to niyou's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pid, frage, antwort, user, created_at
FROM antwortenverlauf
WHERE frage =  'Risiko: Wie empfinden Sie die Kommunikation mit dem Kunden?'
AND (
user, created_at
)
IN (
SELECT user, MAX( created_at ) 
FROM antwortenverlauf

GROUP BY USER               // **this is the only difference**
)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

in your code the inner query only return one raw that was the problem

[image]

Comment: That is not correct. It only selects the Answer from "Nutzer1237". Have a look at the created_at by "Nutzer1234". Its a different than one row before!

Comment: i just done your program in my computer and i got the output.

Comment: Please add a row with q -> risc  user -> 1234 and cat ->  50 than u see what i mean

Comment: new row? or i should edit the existing one. specify the id then (pid)

Comment: i added a new row with cat 50 and user 1234 ,now i got the output  user 1237- cat-33 and user-127 cat-50

Comment: Have a look at the picture! with max(created_at) u only select the maximum of created_at from a user. But the Question from Nutzer1234 'Risiko: Wie empfinden Sie die Kommunikation mit dem Kunden?' is not the maximum of created_at